# Rails: Getting all users from an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Say I have an article model, user model and comment model. If I want to get all users that commented on a particular article is this the best way or is there a better way?

```
User.find(Article.first.comments.pluck(:user_id))
```

Comment: Is this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011713/rails-best-association-model-for-users-posts-comments-model-in-a-forum-kin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

You can add

```
has_many :users, through: :comments
```

to `Article` then just say:

```
@article.users
```

If you don't want to do that for some reason you can do

```
@article.comments.collect(&:user)
```

I think this would be more efficient:

```
@article.comments.includes(:users).collect(&:user)
```

I hope that helps.